# Find density of points from their scatter plot in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

Can I go through equal boxed areas in the scatter plot, so I can calculate how many there are on average on each box?
Or, is there a specific function in python to calculate this?
I don't want a colored density plot, but a number that represents the density of these points in the scatter plot.

Here is for example a plot of the eigenvalues of a random matrix:
[image: Eigenvalues of a random matrix]

How would I find their density?

Comment: there exists a numpy function [np.histogram2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from scipy import linalg as la
e = la.eigvals(my_matrix)
hist,xedges,yedges = np.histogram2d(e.real,e.imag,bins=40,normed=False)
```

So in this case, 'hist' would be a 40x40 array (since bins=40). Its elements are the number of eigenvalues for each bin.

Thanks to @jepio and @plonser for the comments.